# My script is removing white spaces

Tags: php, removing-whitespace

This is a little "cut" from the data.txt:

```
(7220, 'Miecz Swiatla Ksiezyca +', 'Miecz Swiatla Ksiezyca +', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 30000, 100, 7221, 19, 0, 5, 1, 80, 0, 0, 7, 15, 17, 2, 0, 0, 0, 90, 110, 5, 67, 117, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 3, -1),
(2, 'ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713 ', 'Polska Wersja', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0),
(10, 'µµ+0                    ', 'Miecz +0', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 0, 0, 11, 1, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(11, 'µµ+1                    ', 'Miecz +1', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 12, 2, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(12, 'µµ+2                    ', 'Miecz +2', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 13, 3, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 14, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(13, 'µµ+3                    ', 'Miecz +3', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 14, 4, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(14, 'µµ+4                    ', 'Miecz +4', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 15, 5, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 28, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 30, 1, 0),
(15, 'µµ+5                    ', 'Miecz +5', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 16, 6, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 35, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 40, 1, 0),
(16, 'µµ+6                    ', 'Miecz +6', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 17, 7, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 42, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 50, 1, 0),
(17, 'µµ+7                    ', 'Miecz +7', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 18, 8, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 49, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 65, 1, 0),
(18, 'µµ+8                    ', 'Miecz +8', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 19, 9, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 56, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 80, 1, 0),
(19, 'µµ+9                    ', 'Miecz +9', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 2000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 63, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 100, 1, 0),
```

This is a script I use, to generate a query to the `MySQL`:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1250');
$data = file("data.txt"); // returns an array of the lines
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $temp = explode(',', $val);
    $id = substr($temp[0], 1);
    $name = $temp[1];
    $query = 'UPDATE `item_proto`
        SET `name` = ' . $name . '
        WHERE `vnum` = ' . $id . ';';
    echo $query."<Br/>";
}
```

The output is following:

```
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'Miecz Swiatla Ksiezyca +' WHERE `vnum` = 7220;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713 ' WHERE `vnum` = 2;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+0 ' WHERE `vnum` = 10;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+1 ' WHERE `vnum` = 11;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+2 ' WHERE `vnum` = 12;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+3 ' WHERE `vnum` = 13;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+4 ' WHERE `vnum` = 14;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+5 ' WHERE `vnum` = 15;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+6 ' WHERE `vnum` = 16;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+7 ' WHERE `vnum` = 17;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+8 ' WHERE `vnum` = 18;
UPDATE `item_proto` SET `name` = 'µµ+9 ' WHERE `vnum` = 19;
```

The above output, has only one space at the end, but the script is removing all other white spaces, as the `name` is supposed to be 24 characters count (including the white spaces).

So why is my script removing the white spaces from the end of a `name` attr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not.

But if you're viewing those queries in your web browser and haven't changed the Content-Type from `text/html`, then your browser is collapsing whitespaces as it does in HTML.

Either add `header("Content-type: text/plain");` to the start of your script (and swap `<br/>` for `\n`), or just "View Source" in your browser to see the verbatim output.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is happening as you have set `Content-type` as `text/html`. HTML treats multiple white spaces as one. So try using plain text content type.